# My program is stuck in a while loop reading from a file

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        //System.out.print("ok");
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File("EmployeeInfo.txt"));
        //System.out.print(fileReader.nextInt());

        while(fileReader.hasNext()){
            System.out.print("ok");
            int year = 2014;
            //int year = fileReader.nextInt();
            if(year == 2014){

                System.out.print("ok");

            }//end if


        }// end while loop



    }//end main method
```

im not sure why it is stuck in the while loop. i have verified that the program opens the file and can read it.

Comment: You're not advancing the fileReader. Uncomment `//int year = fileReader.nextInt();`

Comment: you keep looping because you have a local variable year whose value is compared against 2014 and this is always true as you are locally updating the year value to 2014 everytime you enter the loop.

Comment: i had this commented out to test what was wrong with the code. now i just get an error:

Comment: put a break once the if statement is true to get out of the loop

Comment: while(fileReader != null){
   
   int year = fileReader.nextInt();
   if(year == 2014){
    
    System.out.print(year);
    
   }//end if
   
   
  }// end while loop

Comment: im getting an error after the compile it is: 2014Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at TheMain.main(TheMain.java:18)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are not calling `nextLine()` (or `nextXXX()`) method inside the `while` loop which means the `Scanner` never advances to the next token.

Here's what the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) of `nextLine()` method says:

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

So, you need to call `nextLine()` inside `while` loop to iterate through the lines and reach end of file in order for control to come out of it.

Comment: Thank you, i figured having nextInt() would advance the scanner. i added a nextLine() and it broke the loop. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with just reading the integer with the scanner is that it leaves the newline character in the buffer which causes the hasNext method to return true. You can use readline() or call next() to clear the new line character.